# Getting connection error while streaming tweets using python 2.6.6

Tags: python, centos, streaming, tweepy

While trying to execute the code for streaming tweets based on a filter i am getting this below mentioned error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "new5.py", line 37, in <module> stream.filter(track=[sys.argv[1]])   
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 428, in filter self._start(async)   
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 346, in _start self._run()   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 239, in _run verify=self.verify)   
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 461, in request resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs) 
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send raise ConnectionError(err, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))
```

Please find below the code i have used.

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import sys
import json

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""


class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print('tweet: ' + json.loads(data)['text'])
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: python %s filter_name" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=[sys.argv[1]])
```

I am using python 2.6.6 on a CentOS6.3

Comment: If that is LITERALLY the code you are using then I imagine you're getting a connection refused because you haven't provided the correct credentials to the API. Have you set up the keys, tokens, and secrets with twitter?

Comment: I have given the correct keys and tokens. Is it something related to the proxy server? Where do i give the proxy connection details to bypass?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your proxy connection is failing and tweepy doesn't have proxy support. You can use [twitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) which has inbuilt proxy support or check [this](https://bitbucket.org/sakito/tweepy). Its a  tweepy fork with proxy implemented